# How to make cells into Command Buttons with VBA and Excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, named-ranges

How might one turn spreadsheet cells into buttons, and execute VBA code, without inserting buttons, shapes or other active-X objects?

Comment: Hyperlink?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660492/running-vba-from-a-hyperlink/32662063#32662063

Comment: @TimWilliams -- Interesting Idea !   Reference includes answers that address rollover and etc. and working on click.   Using the rollover effect, as initially proposed there and elsewhere add utility to popups of shapes (as help/comment)....and other answers/questions to discover how to get the popups to close when no longer hovering on the cell.   I also notice that the vba/code, now executing as a UDF, can't be traced directly, so this may present problems to novices (the workaround is suggested in your link, too)

Answer (score 1):

Using @TimWilliams' suggestion and referenced URL, based on readings there and further, I present some demonstration code, which works for me in Excel 2010:  the `IfError` may not work in earlier versions, and I wonder if it behaves different in later versions.

Note: This code *can not* be debugged as one might with normal VBA.  This is because it is executed on the "spreadsheet side", as a user defined function.

Place a formula in a cell (here, A2):

1. `=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#MyUDF()","CellText"),"Junk")`
2. "CellText" will show in cell A2.
3. The `"#...."` points to the UDF.  In combination with the `Set` statement in the code, it forces a "click" to execute, and only executes once on the click, rather than as a repeatable event executed when hovering and moving across the cell
4. The `=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(...),...)` is a workaround for the #name or other error., seen when using the mere `=HYPERLINK(....)`.

Place this code in a module (a dimension and the UDF):

```
Dim j as integer

Function MyUDF() ' this is a user-defined-function
    'NOTE: can't be traced when executed, 
        'so this creates debugging issues
Set MyUDF = Selection
Range("a1") = j
j = j + 1
End Function
```

Clicking on the URL in A2 will increment the value displayed in A1 - one increment per click.

To observe the hover effect:

1. Comment out the "Set Statement"
2. remove the quotes and pound sign around the UDF reference.  The cell will now show "asdf" instead of "Test".
3. Roll across the URL, and cell A1 will increment as you move/hover.

To get the entire cell to cause execution of the UDF (and the incrementing value), turn on word wrap for the cell.

Notice how with the hover, the code is executed often as you move around in the cell.  For me, the code does not execute if I stop moving while in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

***An Alternative to "putting a button in a cell"***

Select a cell to execute code using the worksheet event: `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

Place the code in the specific sheet's module, not the WorkBook Module.  Color/Border/Text the cell as you please; a cell-is-a-cell on any computer or screen.  I use this to reference help loaded into a userForm, from a look up on a help worksheet, when the user clicks on a short label/description.  This works on merged cells as buttons.  Using cell/buttons avoids Active-X objects complaints from IT.

Things to think on, with the sample code, following:

1. Target.Address returns absolute addresses, using the "$" character
2. Use the `Select Case` in your code, even if you have one cell/button.  This eases the path to adding cell/buttons, later
3. consider using named ranges on the spreadsheet, and reference them in the code.  That way, VBA won't care if you move the cell/button
4. If you have merged cells for which you create a named range, remember that the named range, in the spreadsheet, only points to the top-left cell

   - However, the `Target.Address` for the merged area returns the full range, not just one cell.  If your `Select Case` refers to the address of the `Target`'s top-left cell, you avoid this problem.
   - use `Target.Cells(1,1).Address`
5. Bad choice for merged cells: don't use `MergeArea.Address` (`MergeArea` will not work on merged cells [only works on single cells]; it returns the merged range within which a cell lives.

**Sample Code**

```
'How to Make Cells into Buttons that execute code
' place code in the specific Worksheet module of interest
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' in this example, I create named ranges on the spreadsheet '
            ' [complicated names, here, so you can read what's what]:
      ' one cell:  "Button_OneCellNameRange"
      ' one set of merged cells:  "Button_MergedCellNameRange"
         ' [the reference is the top-left cell, only]

   ' a VBA created cell/button location [not very useful for later sheet edits]
      Dim myVBACellButton As Range
      Set myVBACellButton = Range("B2")

         Debug.Print "Target Address: " & Target.Address
               'merged cells will return a range: eg "$A$1:$D$3"

         Debug.Print "Target.Cells(1,1).Address: " & Target.Cells(1, 1).Address
               'merged cells will return the top left cell, which would match
                  ' a named reference to a merged cell

   Select Case Target.Cells(1, 1).Address
        'if you have merged cells, you must use the ".cells(1,1).address"
        ' and not just Target.Address

      Case Is = "$A$1"
         MsgBox "Hello from: Click on A1"
         ' [execute a procedure/subroutine call, or more code, here...]

      Case Is = myVBACellButton.Address
         MsgBox "Hello from: Click on B2, a VBA referenced cell/button"
            ' "myCellButton" defined as range in VBA

      'using a range named on the spreadsheet itself ...
         ' named ranges allow one to move the cell/button freely,
         ' without VBA worries
      Case Range("Button_OneCellNameRange").Address
         MsgBox "Hello From: Button Click on Button_OneCellNameRange"

      Case Range("Button_MergedCellNamedRange").Address
         'note that the address for merged cells is ONE CELL, the top left
         MsgBox _
            "Hello from: Button_MergedCellNamedRange.Address: " _
                  & Range("Button_MergedCellNamedRange").Address _

      Case Else ' normally you wouldn't be using this, for buttons
         MsgBox "NOT BUTTONS"

   End Select
End Sub
```

[image: Image of the Sheet]