# Excel | Hyperlinks made by formula doesn´t work with hidden sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula =hyperlink() that catches the value -thrown by a vlookup-, and creates the text shown in the hyperlink, and a reference to a sheet with the same name (for example: "group1" hyperlink refers to a1 cell located in sheet "group1".

I´ve tried several solutions, but none worked.

I´ve found a video on youtube, from Mr.Excel, where he explains how does work this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    LinkTo = Target.SubAddress
    WhereBang = InStr(1, LinkTo, "!")
    If WhereBang > 0 Then
        MySheet = Left(LinkTo, WhereBang - 1)
        Worksheets(MySheet).Visible = True
        Worksheets(MySheet).Select
        MyAddr = Mid(LinkTo, WhereBang + 1)
        'Range(MyAddr).Select
        Worksheets(MySheet).Range(MyAddr).Select
    End If


End Sub
```

It work with normal links (created by ctrl + K), but does nothing with links made with HYPERLINK formulas with sheets hiddens.

Thanks!

Comment: also please show the exact formula you're using

Comment: Sorry Guys, I´ll post the things I´ve already tried. I tagged it with VBA cos I tried creating some macros.

Comment: `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` doesn't work with HYPERLINK() links

Comment: And do u know any way to make a link created with HYPERLINK() function work with hidden sheets? I´ve seen this problem solved with buttons, but I need this to be an hyperlink, because the name and the anchor are both dynamic

Comment: What does "work with hidden sheets" mean? Are you trying to link *to* a sheet that's hidden? By definition, a hidden sheet can't be navigated to. Make it visible if you want hyperlinks to it.

Comment: You might be able to leverage the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32665442/9245853)

Comment: @BigBen - I'm testing that and a function called that way doesn't seem to be able to unhide a sheet...

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess that clicking hyperlink made by function calls another event, but I dunno what function is it

Comment: There's no available event which is triggered by clicking on a HYPERLINK() link

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams!, I gess i´ll need to get a workaround for it